# Android layouts under subfolders

Tags: android, layout

Is it possible to create subfolders under res/layout and place the layout XML files there so that one can call a view like `setContentView(R.layout.questions.create);` or `setContentView(R.layout.questions/create);` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my tests, no.

You might want to consider a naming convention:

- questions_create
- questions_list
- answers_list

Or, investigate Android library projects: http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-library-projects.html - seems pretty good to add more structure.